# Why does the DC level of the integrator output change?

Tags: operational-amplifier

In the following circuit (Fig 1), an integrating circuit is added to the output of the comparator.

If I vary the potentionmeter, the pulse width or the duty cycle of the comparator output (square wave) changes as well as the DC level of the integrator output (triangular wave) changes (Fig. 2.)

Can someone please explain why the DC level of the integrator output changes in this case? (In Fig 2, the triangular wave moves down.)

[image]

[image: Fig 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *If I vary the potentiometer, the pulse width or the duty cycle of the
> comparator output (square wave) changes*

Yes that happens and, as a result of that happening, the average level of that adjusted PWM signal will also change. If the duty cycle gets closer to unity then the average level rises. If the duty cycle gets closer to zero then the average level falls. The two are inseparable. The peak values (positive and negative) are clamped to values set by your LEDs but, the average value has to change.

> *Can someone please explain why the DC level of the integrator output
> changes in this case?*

An integrator (with gain limiting as per your schematic) will attempt to follow the average DC level of the input. It's inevitable.

Comment: Thanks @Andy. Can I ask you one more question for the same circuit?  If I remove the negative power supply, I get positive saturation at the integrator output. Would you please say why do I get positive saturation in this case?

Comment: I don't know what part you have used - maybe it is a data sheet thing?

Comment: I was asked to introduce a fault in this circuit by removing the negative power supply connection (i.e VEE of both op amp and -12V in voltage divider are removed) and then explain why in such situation the integrator output goes to positive saturation. Please note that in this figure the VCC and VEE are not shown.

Comment: If you disconnect the op-amp -Vsupply pin, anything is possible because this is an illegal situation for the part. The only place the output can go is the positive rail of course.